# GCM speed and DB design conflict

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, google-cloud-messaging

I'm puzzled and looking for a way out here. I will appreciate any help:

I am sending notifications from a server to Android devices using GCM. In Mysql, I have a User Table (UT) with user ID, user data and GCM registration ID. I also have a User Notifications Table (UNT) in which I store the notification types that each user is registered to. This table includes the user ID and the notification type ID.

When Sending the notification, I need to go through UNT and build an array of all user IDs that are registered to this type of notification. Then I need to go through the UT and get the GCM Registration ID for each user and send the notification.

DB design-wise, I believe that this is the right way to do it. However, in notification sending, speed is a major issue if I want a million users to get the notification a few seconds after sending it. Going through 2 tables significantly increases the processing time (I measured 47 seconds for 1 million users when going through both tables compared to 17 seconds when going through 1 table).

The question is will it be right to store the GCM registration ID also in the UNT so I won't have to go through the UT? Again... DB design wise it is incorrect but GCM wise, it might be the best solution.
If you know of additional methods to solve this issue, I'll be happy to hear about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always decide to hold data redundantly. Yes, this means de-normalizing data, but is something that is often done when you need quick access to many data - in data warehouses for instance.

The dbms even supports this by ON UPDATE CASCADE. But GCM registration ID must be unique in the table.

- So either it is unique in UT, then just add the field in UNT, fill it, and create the foreign key with the cascade option.
- Or it is not unique in UT, then you need a GCM table (which you should have then anyhow) and have this foreign key from UNT to GCM then. (But in this case you would have to think about if it is really a user notification table you need or a a GCM notification table or both.)

Comment: Thanks, you have teach me something new that I really needed. Let me understand: ON UPDATE CASCADE means that every change in the GCM registration ID in UT will automatically update all rows in UNT with the same GCM ID, without me having to do anything? If that's so, this is great, and I will now google for how to implement it on my current tables. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is what it does. But the GMC Registration ID must be unique in the parent table (and have a unique constraint of course).